# d3 event handler on node not in HTML DOM

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dom-events

I use a template system which returns the SVG code generated by d3 code. (see [d3 issue](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/825) for info how to do this)

Everything works fine, except the event listeners set with the `on` method of d3. They are not added to the DOM tree.

Below is a minimal example of code which will not work. If d3 modifies directly the existing DOM tree, everything works *(uncomment line 3 instead of 1 and 2)*.

Any idea what to change to get this to work?

```
svg = d3.select(document.createElement('div'));
svg

//d3.select('body') // if you use this line INSTEAD of the first two, everything works as expected

.append("div")    
.append("div")
.text('Text')
.on('mouseover', function() { alert('Test'); });

//alert(svg.node().innerHTML);
$("body").html(svg.node().innerHTML);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0rLarspu/2/)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that in one case you act on an element not yet in the DOM of the page : `svg = d3.select(document.createElement('div'));`

While on the other you act on an element already on the page `svg = d3.select('body')`

D3 can't add a listener to something not in the DOM yet.

Look at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0rLarspu/4/), where i add the `mouseover` after appending the `div` in the page.

Comment: Yes, I already got the difference, so the answer is that this is not possible with D3. Would be interesting to know why, because the `innerHTML` could return HTML tags with `onClick` attributes.